# How to capture output of subprocess.call

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, raspberry-pi3, discord.py

I have made a script that tells me the temperature of my Raspberry Pi 3, but there is a problem with the script.  The result output is the bot saying "Your RPI3 temp is currently 0". What is wrong with my code?

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def vcgencmdmeasure_temp(ctx):
    if ctx.message.author.id == "412372079242117123":
        await bot.say("OK....")
        return_code = subprocess.call("vcgencmd measure_temp", shell=True)
        await bot.say("KK done")
        await bot.say("Your RPI3 temp is currently: {}".format(return_code))
    else:
        await bot.say("Error user lacks perms(only bot owner can run this)")
```

EDIT: i know want to run any command. 
Current script

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def rpicmd(ctx, *args):

```
if ctx.message.author.id == "412372079242117123":
    mesg = ''.join(args)
    mesg = str(mesg)
    command_output = subprocess.check_output(mesg, shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
    await bot.say(command_output)
else:
    await bot.say("No noob")
```

and i get the error:

```
raise CommandInvokeError(e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an 
 exception: CalledProcessError: Command 'vcgencmdmeasure_temp' returned 
  non-zero exit status 12
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return_code` will have the return code of the process. When a process exists successfully (without error), it returns a code of `0`. If it errors, it returns a code of `1` (or something non-zero). If you want the output of the program (that it prints to `stdout`), this is one way to get it:

```
p = subprocess.run("vcgencmd measure_temp", shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
result = p.stdout.decode()
await bot.say("Your RPI3 temp is currently: {}".format(result))
```

---

Note: a similar method applies to capturing error and warning messages - you may pipe them using the `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` argument and then retrieve using `p.stderr.decode()`.

Comment: Then i use await bot.say(result)?

Comment: @botbotbotty Yes. I've updated my answer to match your original code.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `subprocess.check_output` to get the response from your command.

From the docs:

> subprocess.check_output(args, *, stdin=None, stderr=None, shell=False,
>   universal_newlines=False)
>
> Run command with arguments and return its output as a byte string.

Using `call` gives the returncode:

> subprocess.call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None,
>   shell=False)
>
> Run the command described by args. Wait for command to
>   complete, then return the returncode attribute.